how do I get a window.parent.postMessage (can't use CefSharp.PostMessage)?
I've been reading the CefSharp documentation, and done quite a bit of googling, and I do see examples like this.
It seems that they are saying that if you want JavaScript message to your C#, start using CefSharp.PostMessage.
I can't use CefSharp.PostMessage.  I have no control over the Javascript or the Code.
But, I do know that it at some point sends a message to window.parent.postMessage.
When that Javascript is executed by the webpage, how can I get the data in my C# (using CefSharp)?
EDIT:
To answer the question posed in the comments (just a quick test, not even trying to get the actual data returned):
    private void ChromiumWebBrowser1_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Frame.IsMain)
        {
            chromiumWebBrowser1.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
                window.parent.postmessage = function()
                {
                     CefSharp.PostMessage('test');
                }
            ");
        }
    }

Leads to me not getting one event here:
    private void ChromiumWebBrowser1_JavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var foo = (string)e.Message;
    }

Of note: When we hit the original URL, it must go through something like three re-directs before it lands on the page that will javascript execute a postMessage.

can you try basically follow the link provided, replaceing document.body.onmouseup by window.parent.postMessage ? (adapting the arguments accordingly, if required, to the handler function)

Start by calling console.log to confirm you've got the correct method to override.
